# AHK: need help in autohotkey script

Tags: autohotkey

I need help to put a delay in the script below because its too fast.
I tried "sleep 200" but it didnt work.
The script:

```
*V::
    While GetKeyState("V","P")
        Send, {C}
Return
F12::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sleep 200` would work just fine, I'd assume you just placed it in there wrong.
Here's a working version:

```
*v::
    While GetKeyState("v","P")
    {
        SendInput, C
        Sleep, 200
    }
Return
F12::ExitApp
```

Misc fixes/improvements:

- Changed to lower case letters in the hotkey definition and the `GetKeyState()` function.
  Doesn't actually make a difference in this instance, but sometimes it does make a difference, so good practice to use the correct case.
- Switched over to [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail), it's faster and more reliable.
- Removed the `{}`s from around `C`.
  They don't belong in there. They're only used to escape characters that have a special meaning in a send command. And in some cases it could even cause unexpected behavior. More about this from the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).